# Tiny text box in "Manage Off-Topic Close Reasons" tool

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, custom-close-reasons

In [`/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic`](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic), the text box to add a new reason is tiny:

[image]

Safari 12.1.1 / macOS 10.14.5.

Comment: Able to repro in Win 10 Chrome 77.